# Does TPOT support multi-label text classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, automl, tpot

How can I run TPOT to give me suggestions on what algorithm to use for a multi-label text classification? My data is already cleaned and divided into training and testing sets.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can use TPOT for multi-label text classification.

Comment: how is that possible, TPOT does not support MLC